# How to merge HTML, CSS, JS, and images into a single HTML file for offline use

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple web app project that performs one task and is built with a single HTML, CSS (Bootstrap), JS, and some images. This program is meant to be used locally, offline, and in the browser only.

Is there a way I can merge/concatenate all of the HTML, CSS, JS, and image files into a single HTML file?

Ideally, I'd like to have one HTML file that contains all the necessary code and resources so the app can be used offline by just opening the HTML file in a browser.

The main requirements are:

All CSS, JS, and images are contained within the single HTML file
No external file requests are made that require a web connection
The HTML file is self-contained and can be opened locally on a computer
What is the best way to concatenate/merge everything into a single HTML file for offline use?

Comment: `<style>` inside `head` and `<script>` inside `body` ?

Comment: @eekinci I mean some other way than manually import css and js in html, cause Bottstrap has very large files with many lines of code, so it will be a very messy HTML file

Comment: [Get started with Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: [Starter template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template)

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but why? Keep your HTML as single file, then have a local version of images, css and js in a sensible file structure. It will be easier to manage in the long run. Use relative paths and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could hack something together. JS and CSS can be included in HTML, of course, but if you’re using large libraries like Boostrap then yes, things could get messy. Images can be converted to data URLs. So it’s doable, and you can use something like [grunt-inline](https://github.com/chyingp/grunt-inline) to help automate it.

If you’re prepared to consider other file types, Safari can save any webpage to a [`.webarchive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webarchive) file which includes everything to make the page available offline. However, such files are only viewable in Safari. Chrome allows you to save any webpage to an [`.mht`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) file (use “Web page, Single File” when saving) but again, browser support is limited.

Chrome also offers an option it calls “Web page, Complete” which creates an `.html` file and an accompanying folder containing the images and other dependencies. I recommend you consider this option carefully. Although you don’t get a single file, it has the advantages of being editable and cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score -2):

Simply you should add css in head section with style tag and js with script tag and upload images on drive and place their url where you want your image thus you can make a single html file containing all